# How to change the text on the page refresh message pop-up?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web page that gets refreshed, when something happens on any of its children pages.  When it happens, the IE pop-up appears with the following message: "To display the webpage again, the web browser needs to resend the information you've previously submitted.  If you were making a purchase, you should click Cancel to avoid a duplicate transaction.  Otherwise, click Retry to display".  See the image attached:

[image]

I'm ok with all that, but I was wondering if there's a way to change the actual text of the message, for example, removing the last sentence.  I know this pop-up can't be tampered with, but perhaps there's a way to replace it with a custom made pop-up, serving the same function, but showing a different text.  I assume first I would have to suppress the original message, then call a confirm box in a beforeupdate function, where clicking OK (for example) would resend the information submitted and Cancel would let you remain on the page without refreshing it.  However, my Javascript and JQuery knowledge is a bit rusty and I'm not sure how to implement it properly.  Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: This is a browser alert and cannot be modified, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Don't use `<form method='post'>`  then you won't get this alert, instead hook into the form `submit`, show a custom dialog, then, on confirm, make an ajax call.